# Scan and Advertise in Gatt Service UUID format using the AltBeacon library

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I've written a piece of code to advertise in the GattService UUID, though I'm still not able to figure out the kind of parser i should be running through it to accept only results that are advertising in the same format and is a valid pattern of advertisement.

Code to advertise in Gatt Service UUID:

```
public void startGattServiceAdvertising() {
    BluetoothAdapter defaultAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (defaultAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    String uniqueId = "Hello world";
    if (uniqueId.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    defaultAdapter.setName(uniqueId);
    BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = defaultAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
    AdvertiseSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_LOW)
            .setConnectable(true);

    String userId = "4539c428-0c3c-4606-b701-98bde9c39a82";
    ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(userId));

    LogHelper.d("Parcel: ", "UUID: " + pUuid.getUuid());
    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .addServiceUuid(pUuid)
            .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false).build();

    LogHelper.d("Parcel: ", "Service UUID: " + data.getServiceUuids().toString());
    if (advertiser != null) {
        try {
            advertiser.startAdvertising(settingsBuilder.build(), data, getAdvertiseCallback());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Adding common exception just to retry this if anything goes wrong in the first time
            // (Chinese devices facing some legacy data issue)
            //Some OEM shows Advertising data too large exception,so not sending txPowerLevel
        }
    }
}
```

This advertises in the exact way I'm looking for and I'm able to detect the same on other devices too, my only concern lies in the changes that i need to make on library end for me to validate this particular format, the way AltBeacon library does for other formats by calling the `fromScanData(..)` method. Do i need to advertise something extra or what changes are supposed to be made on scanning end for me to run the detected beacon through the parser successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The code shown just emits a standard BLE 128-bit service UUID advertisement that happens to have a user id placedd inside the Service UUID field.

This is fine -- but it gives you no way of determining on the receiving side if this is one of "your" advertisements or one that is not and instead originates from a hardware device.  An Apple Watch, for example, will emit a particular 128 bit service UUID that uses this same format.  So if your Android app scanning for this advertisement comes across an Apple Watch, it will think it is a particular user id.

Standard beacon formats like iBeacon, AltBeacon and Eddystone have at least three parts, the fist of which solves this problem::

1. A set of static bytes whose value never changes, used to indicate that it is indeed  this type of beacon
2. A dynamic set of bytes that are other beacon identifier
3. A measured power field used for distance estimates (optional)

The format you show is missing the fist component.  As a result you can't tell if it is your beacon type

One note of caution about using service advertisements if you need iOS interoperability.  While iOS can scan for and transmit these advertisements, it cannot transmit this format in the background.  Further, it cannot attach service data at all, making point (1) above impossible.  For this same reason, Eddystone formats cannot be advertised at all on iOS.

Comment: Yes. Makes sense. So based on this explanation there's not going to be a workaround possible for me to detect if this is one of the beacon i am expecting or not right?

Comment: There are Android-only ways, but none that work with iOS transmitting and receiving.

Comment: Can you share some resources for me to look around for Android-only ways?

Comment: Eddystone-UID is a similar service advertisement you can send on Android only and receive on both platforms: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html. Transmitting: https://droidmentor.com/beacon-transmitter/